# C# Multithreading - Why is 2 threads call the same function?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

I have a C# code with 2 threads. It calls the print method, but It always have the same time .. why?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace MultiThreading
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(new Program().print));
            Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(new Program().print));
            thread.Name = "Thread1";
            thread2.Name = "thread2";  
            thread.Start();
            thread2.Start();

        }

        public void print()
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int time = r.Next(3000);
            System.Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + ", " + (double)time/1000 + " secs!");
            Thread.Sleep(time);           
        }
    }
}
```

Ok so I hame 2 threads, and each one have the "print" delegate.

print generates a number `time` what what `time` seconds.

`thread` and `thread2` generates the same time always, how to fix it?

Comment: Because `System.Random` is broken-by-design.

Answer (score 2):

Your confusion is not because of threads but because of the Random Number generator.

MSDN says :

> The random number generation starts from a seed value. If the same seed is used repeatedly, the same series of numbers is generated. One way to produce different sequences is to make the seed value time-dependent, thereby producing a different series with each new instance of Random.

Try replacing your new Random line with this and see the difference.

```
Random r = new Random(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
```

I have just added a new random seed so that every thread gets a different value.

**Edit:** Instead of ManagedThreadId, you can use any other value of your choosing for the seed value. You need to make sure it is different to get different sequences of random numbers from your Random object. As to why ManagedThreadId is not a very good choice, please see comment below.

Comment: It should be mentioned though that ThreadIds may be reused after a thread terminates, so another thread might be seeded the same value easily.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks! Have included the note in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [System.Threading.Thread.Sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx) method between to thread start methods to start them with interval.

```
thread.Start();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
thread2.Start();
```

Comment: To explain what Adil did here, he added a small gap so that the default random seed becomes different. `By default, the parameterless constructor of the Random class uses the system clock to generate its seed value, while its parameterized constructor can take an Int32 value based on the number of ticks in the current time. However, because the clock has finite resolution, using the parameterless constructor to create different Random objects in close succession creates random number generators that produce identical sequences of random numbers.`

Answer (score 0):

i guess, the problem is the call of the Random() method! Try using different seeds with every Thread otherwise you always get the same random number!

Answer (score 0):

Call `Randomize()` before thread startups.
This generates new seeds for your random functions to use!